# karma mocha chai phantomJS - Can't find variable: exports\nat src/index.js:3:30

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I am trying to test code for a javascript module written in ES6 using karma mocha chai and phatomJS.

Running `karma start` returns the following output to the console:

```
19 03 2018 17:39:11.428:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
19 03 2018 17:39:11.435:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
19 03 2018 17:39:11.436:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
19 03 2018 17:39:11.440:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
19 03 2018 17:39:12.488:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket RSlRhr_U-N5Ge7FIAAAA with id 75824261
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports\nat src/index.js:3:30",
    "str": "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports\nat src/index.js:3:30"
  }
```

This is the test I am trying to run:

```
describe('returnString', () => {
  it('should return a string', () => {
    //const myString = returnString('Miha')
    expect(true).to.equal(true)
  })
})
```

This is my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Mar 19 2018 16:40:36 GMT+0100 (CET)

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',
    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/**/*.js'
    ],
    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],
    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel']
    },
    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],
    // web server port
    port: 9876,
    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,
    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,
    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,
    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Where does this error mean, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: The error means that there is a variable being referenced in line 3, column 30 of `src/index.js` that hasn't being declared or defined.

Comment: did you find the solution？I meet similar problem today

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out that the error was caused by an export clause improperly transpiled by Babel:

```
export * from './somePackage'
```

I found more info [here](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/issues/1133).